# Week calculation in the query

Tags: oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

Using oracle database and the table is like this

```
id    sdate        offer
1   16-04-13       offer1
2   11-04-13       offer2
3   21-04-13       offer4
4   31-03-13       offer5
5   14-04-13       offer8
6   10-04-13       offer4
7   15-04-13       offer1
```

I want to calculate weeks as w1 w2 and so on from the `sysdate`.
Example:

- for `id=1`, `sdate` falls on 16-04-13 so it is `week1`.
- for `id=5`, `sdate` falls on 14-04-13 so it is `week2`

The result should be like this

```
id  week   offer
1    w1   offer1
5    w2   offer8
.............
```

Comment: 4/14 is a Sunday and you want it treated as the week prior to Tuesday 4/16. Does your week run from Monday to Sunday? Also, just to verify: do you want "this week" to be "week 1", "last week" to be "week 2", "two weeks ago" to be "week 3", etc?

Comment: There is no day concept...Just want to subtract 7 days from the sysdate and i:e week1 for me.. and so on

Answer (score 1):

To treat today and the prior six days as "week 1", then the seven days before that as "week 2", and so forth, try something like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  'w' || TO_CHAR(TRUNC((TRUNC(SYSDATE) - sdate) / 7) + 1) as week,
  offer
FROM ... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

you also got a format for that. 
from [OTN](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=685308)

```
select to_char( date '2008-01-04', 'IW' ) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could combine the functions [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129) and [`DECODE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions049.htm#SQLRF00631), for example:

```
sql> select decode(to_char(sdate, 'W'),
                   '1', 'w1',
                   '2', 'w2',
                   '3', 'w3',
                   '4', 'w4',
                   '5', 'w5')
       from table1;
```

Comment: select 'w'||to_char(sdate, 'W') from table1 ?

Answer (score 0):

One date minus another date gives their difference in days.  Divide by seven to get difference in weeks.  Use `floor()` to get rid of the remainder. Add 1 because you want to start at W1 not W0.

```
select id
        , sdate
        , 'W'||trim(to_char(floor((sysdate - sdate)/7) + 1)) as wkno
from your_table
/
```

Note that `wkno` comes out as 'W1', 'W2', ... 'W10' which won't sort numerically.  There are various workarounds, somne more obvious than opthers, if that's something which botehrs you.